# Nginx installation with PHP

Tags: php, linux, nginx, fpm

I have installed nginx and PHP into my machine.
I want to know the difference between these to configuration when using 
PHP-fpm.

```
> fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000; 
            or  
>fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

which configuration is good for production servers, what is the benefit, what is the difference between the two configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` is a TCP connection.

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;` is a unix socket connection.

Both are suitable for production use, TCP allows you to connect via IP  on an arbitrary port. The socket is filesystem based.

If you have a web server and php running on separate servers then the TCP approach would be the way to go. If they're on the same server, the socket configuration would be better . Sockets run faster due to not having the TCP overhead.

Comment: regarding this tutorial, it says to change like this 
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;  (https://medium.com/@richb_/tweaking-nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-to-fix-502-bad-gateway-errors-and-optimise-performance-on-17465f41fd87)

Comment: Nothing I posted is incorrect. [Here are others verifying this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91774/performance-of-unix-sockets-vs-tcp-ports)... [And some more](https://serverfault.com/questions/195328/unix-socket-vs-tcp-ip-hostport)

Comment: [Another source](https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/7289/nginx-php-fpm-unix-socket-or-tcp-ip-for-fastcgi-pass).... [And another source](http://iallex.com/php_fpm-of-unix-sockets-vs-tcp-ports/)

Comment: [How fast are Unix sockets](https://blog.myhro.info/2017/01/how-fast-are-unix-domain-sockets).... [Benchmarking IP and Unix sockets](https://blog.myhro.info/2017/01/benchmarking-ip-and-unix-domain-sockets-for-real)